# App is sometimes not listed under Notification Access settings in Android

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, notification-listener

**Goal**: I need open `Notification Access` settings to Enable/Disable read notifications by user.
**Problem**: Sometimes app is not in the list. For example: App is in the list after install debug build variant, but if I enable and disable `Notification Access` and next re-open `Notification Access` app is not in the list. I cannot enable it again. When device is rebooted, app is still not in the list. Sometimes app is not in the list immediately after installation debug build variant. Sometimes is or is not in the list after installation from Google Play.

How does `Notification Access` list work?
Docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService

Register service with permission in Manifest:

```
<application
    ...
    <service
        android:name=".service.NotificationListener"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

Call `Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS` from Activity (only testing):

```
//Test:
fun onCreate() {
    handler.postDelayed(()-> {
        startActivityForResult(Intent(Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SETTINGS), 123);
    }, 3000);
}
```

Service class:

```
public class NotificationListener extends NotificationListenerService {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi. Did you find a solution for that problem?

Comment: Hello @AugustoCarmo. Not yet :-|

Comment: No worries. One user reported the same thing (Samsung J6, Android 10). No other user has ever reported that problem before, it's odd it's not appearing on that list just for him.

Comment: Hello @AugustoCarmo, Hello t0m... no solution ? I have the same problem currently

Comment: Hello, no solution